# Proof that product of all real roots divided by product of all complex roots of some polynomial is a real positive number

Tags: polynomials, complex-numbers

I've been trying this one for a while and couldn't match any strategy that showed up on class with this one.

So we have polynomial $$p \in \mathbb{R}[x] $$

and also we know that $$ p(0) \neq 0$$

$a - $ is a product of all real roots of that polynomial $p$

$b - $ is a product of all complex roots of that polynomial $p$

Show that: $$ a\cdot b^{-1}$$

is a real positive number

How to approach this task?

Comment: How can it have complex coefficients if it belongs to $\mathbf R[x]$?

Comment: Presumably you mean to write *roots* rather than *coefficients*. Also, can you show that the product of all complex roots is real?

Comment: Yes. Roots. I can't

Comment: Perhaps I am misunderstanding the question. $p(x)=x+1$ has one real root, which is $-1$. The product of all real roots is $-1$ and the product of all complex roots is the empty product, $1$. The ratio is negative for this $p$.

Answer (score 1):

If $p$ has only real coefficients and $p(a+ib)=0$ then the conjugate is a root too -- ie., $p(a-ib)=0$. Thus $b$ is the product of complex numbers and their conjugates, and that makes $b$ real and non-zero. For example $x^3-1=0$ has three roots $1, \ (-1+i\sqrt3)/2, \ (-1-i\sqrt3)/2$.

Comment: Yes right. But still I have to reason about signs of real roots. Or am I missing sth? For example $z^3 + z^2 + z + 1$ has roots $z_{1} = -1; z_{2}=i, z_{3}=-i$

Comment: For $p(x)=x^3+1$ we have $a=-1$ and $b=(1+sqrt3)/2 * (1-sqrt3)/2$, and so $a/b=-1$. So $a/b$ is a real number, but not necessarily positive. TomTom's example gives the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

HINT: the product $a\cdot b$ is the last coefficient (with a sign) so it's real